# gradle Error:Could not connect to server

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android studio project couldn't be compiled due to this gradle error

> Error:Could not connect to server [2a4d9e5f-6a2b-4c85-a0da-9f82a5ca8169 port:37079, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]].
>
> Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].

I'm using arch linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved now.Problem was with my linux.

Gradle started building after configuring Apache server in the system.